# How to capture the contents of DOS based executable file dynamically which keeps open for processing?

Tags: vb.net, dos, capture, output

Team,

I would appreciate your help on this,

**Background of my project:** I have a executable file e.g. abcd.exe which is actually a kind of server which opens itself in a MS DOS window and once launch, it keeps running. As mentioned since it is a server, it keeps logging some log traces and keeps adding new lines in DOS window one by one. This server needs some parameter to start so here the parameter is path of configuration file wherein all the config details are saved. So, to start this server, I need to provide in command prompt,

*Start > Run > CMD

*abdc.exe -lookup "C:\MyServer\Bin\designConfig.properties"*

To avoid manual steps, I have created batch file e.g. abcd.bat with below lines

"*TITLE: MY SERVER - NODE 1234 (SERVER)*"

*abdc.exe -lookup "C:\MyServer\Bin\designConfig.properties"*

**My Machine and specification**

- Above mentioned abdc.exe file is a 64 bit server. My OS: Windows 7 64
  Bit Platform: VB Visual Studio 2012 or MS Access VBA

**My Requirement**

Now I have created a VB Form, multiple line textbox & button. I want,

1. Once I click on that button, it should lookup the executable file or batch file and launch the abcd.exe server program by accepting the parameter. (I am done with this using below code)

=======================

```
    Dim abc As New Process
    Dim abcinfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    abcinfo.FileName = "C:\ABCD\abdc.bat""
    abcinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    abcinfo.RedirectStandardError = True

    abcinfo.UseShellExecute = False
    abcinfo.ErrorDialog = False

    abc.StartInfo = abcinfo
    abc.Start()
    Dim abclog As System.IO.StreamReader = abc.StandardError
    abc.BeginOutputReadLine()
    TextBox1.Text = abclog.ReadToEnd()
    abc.WaitForExit()
```

=======================

1. This opens up the executable file i.e. server but CMD screen appears as blank and I have close it to check the details in textbox. Once I close it, textbox displays the contents of the ABC server which is just closed. I can have the contents but my server is not running now!!
2. So I want that once I click the 'Start Server' button, (a) it should launch the exe program i.e. server, (b) keep the window invisible (the dos window it uses should not be visible to user nor should minimized on taskbar.) (c) Captures the contents of that DOS window and display them in the textbox on my form (d) Most important, update the contents of the abc server whenever new traces are logged in the server screen i.e. new line added on DOS screen.

Basically, I will be having multiple instaces of this server intance and I dont want users to see at every instance to check the logs. Once they select perticular abc server instance from listbox, textbox should display the live contents from associated DOS executable window.

I have searched lots of thread but did not find the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

P.S: This server is developed in C and I believe is not a console application.

Thanks, Prashant

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I couldn't quite figure out what you are trying to do, but if you want to redirect output in DOS-window (=cmd.exe), here's how to do it:

```
your.exe yourparameter1 yourparameter2 >redirect_here.log 2>&1
```

The first `>` redirects the sysout to `redirect_here.log` -file and the `2>&1` redirects the syserr to the same file.

If you want to track what is written to the `redirect_here.log` -file in another DOS-window, you need to use `tail.exe`. If I remember correctly, you can find the `tail.exe` in Windows Resource Kit, but I use one bundled with [UnxUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/). It's a zip -package, the `tail.exe` is found in \usr\local\wbin\ -folder along with other useful tools. Here's how use `tail.exe`:

```
tail -f redirect_here.log
```

The `-f` -switch means that you want the `tail.exe` to show the new lines as they appear in the `redirect_here.log`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply however; let me put this in simple manner as what I am trying to do,

1. I re-designed my programm in VBA and I am now launching the 
server.exe as below,

Sub run_start_batch()

retVal = Shell(server_start_path & parameter, vbHide)

end sub
2. This button click event launches the server very well and server keeps running within command prompt. As it starts, it keeps logging the traces in its console, like below,

Assume below are the lines in Server console,

2012-11-05 Process started from."C:\Server_home"
2012-11-05 Process Id: 5240

Comment: 3. Since i have launched this exe program using VBA, I have captured the process ID which it creates in windows task manager. Now what Is it possible by any means to capture the above logs (live logs) and display them in the textbox field which I have on my form? I have timer object so I can check the console periodically and capture the latest logs.

Hope I have explained it correctly, Please help.

Thanks, Prashant